# Splitting a list in Python based off of Dictionary all words?

Tags: python

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dictionary=PyDictionary() 


SplitTextList = TextList.read().split(PyDictionary.)
```

So I have a bunch of code in between, obviously, but I end up with a list called 'TextList'. How do I take that list and split all the values inside into separate elements based off the words in a dictionary, perhaps even giving me the number of times each word was used?

Comment: Can you include expected output?

Comment: Can't help unless you give an example of input and output and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Is it this [PyDictionary](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDictionary/1.5.2)?

Comment: @PriyeshKumar Here's what I get as my expected output- everything getting to this point works like a charm which is why I didnt post it.

Comment: `TextList.read().split(PyDictionary.)` doesn't make sense. Can you post a _small_ example of `TextList` so we can see how your data is formatted?

Comment: We don't want to see your whole program, just a [mcve] that focuses on this particular issue.

Comment: Yeah sorry guys: here's a sample of the expected output: (/python/cpython/tree/v3.3.1/Parser/firstsets.c) [ v3.3.1rc1\

Comment: Is it a local file, remote url or just the output?

Comment: @PriyeshKumar Both a local file and the output of the program. It is the output, but it's saved into the local file TextList

Comment: Giving the name of the sample is not giving the sample, please edit your question and add a sample of it. For example, you can give a small snippet of code that works which creates a `PyDictionary` and then what will you expect to get from a function with this input. Also, it will help to see what have you done to know what are you missing